# show select checkbox looping from ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, loops, codeigniter, checkbox

i want to show checkbox looping from db, if i try to select data id_kendaraan in field then show the data from that id.

this my view code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tambah" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah Pemeliharaan</h3>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Data/Pemeliharaan/Tambah">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Nama Kendaraan</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <select class="form-control"  name="id_kendaraan" id="id_kendaraan" required>
                            <option>Pilih Kendaraan</option>
                            <?php
                            if(!empty($kendaraan_)) {
                            foreach ($kendaraan_ as $isi) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $isi['id_kendaraan']?>"><?php echo $isi['nama']?> - <?php echo $isi['platno']?></option>
                            <?php }} ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $index =0;          
                    foreach ($subkriteria_ as $kr_key => $kriteria) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><?php echo $kriteria['nama_kriteria'] ?></label> 
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input type="hidden" name="status_pemeliharaan" value="1" class="form-control">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_kriteria[]" value="<?php echo $kriteria['id_kriteria'] ?>" class="form-control">  
                            <?php if(!empty($kriteria['sub'])) { ?> 
                            <select class="form-control"  name="isi_kriteria[]" required>
                                <option>Pilih Sub Kriteria</option>
                                <?php $no = 1; foreach ($kriteria['sub'] as $data)     { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['namasubkriteria'] ?> - <?php echo $data['value'] ?></option>
                                <?php  $no++; } ?>
                            </select>
                            <?php } else if($kriteria['link']=='tahun_beli') { ?>
                                <input name="isi_kriteria[]" value="" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Isi Kriteria..." readonly required>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <input name="isi_kriteria[]" value="" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Isi Kriteria..." required>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">tes</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="id_sparepart[]" value=""> //my trouble
                        <input type="text" name="sparepart" value=""> //my trouble
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Tutup</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_kendaraan').on('input',function(){
            
        var id_kendaraan=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url('Data/Pemeliharaan/GetKendaraanById')?>",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : {id_kendaraan: id_kendaraan},
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data,function(id_kendaraan, tahun_beli, jenis){
                    $('[name="isi_kriteria[]"]').val(data.tahun_beli);
                    $('[name="id_jenis"]').val(data.id_jenis);
                    $('[name="id_sparepart[]"]').val(data.id_sparepart); //my trouble
                    $('[name="sparepart"]').val(data.sparepart); //my trouble
                        
                });
                    
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

on this code, if I select a kendaraan from the select form then data appears according to the selected kendaraan.
it is working, but on the checkbox not show data sparepart for looping from database.

this my controller:

```
function GetKendaraanById(){
        $id_kendaraan=$this->input->post('id_kendaraan');
        $data=$this->PemeliharaanModel->GetById($id_kendaraan); ;
        echo json_encode($data);
      }
```

i get data from view `$id_kendaraan` for my parameter.

this my model:

```
function GetById($id_kendaraan){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_kendaraan');
        $this->db->join('tb_sparepart', 'tb_sparepart.id_jenis = tb_kendaraan.id_jenis');
        $this->db->where('tb_kendaraan.id_kendaraan',$id_kendaraan);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
                $hasil=array(
                    'tahun_beli' => $data->tahun_beli,
                    'id_jenis' => $data->id_jenis,
                    'id_sparepart' => $data->id_sparepart,
                    'sparepart' => $data->sparepart,
                    );
            }
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
```

field tahun_beli, id jenis is success to showing in the view.
but the checkbox from sparepart is not looping just show one data.

[image: checkbox]
after selecting the nama kendaraan the checkbox should appear according to the type of kendaraan,  data circled in the image should appear more checkbox

thx for helping me

[image: this after change my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the query on your model because it has a different format to show (I assume you want to get one `kendaraan` data with multiple `sparepart` data) :

```php
function GetById($id_kendaraan){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_kendaraan');
    $this->db->where('tb_kendaraan.id_kendaraan',$id_kendaraan);
    $query_kendaraan = $this->db->get();
    
    $hasil = false;
    if($query_kendaraan->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data_kendaraan = $query_kendaraan->row();
        $hasil = [
            'tahun_beli' => $data_kendaraan->tahun_beli,
            'id_jenis' => $data_kendaraan->id_jenis,
            'spareparts' => [] // empty array, to be filled with spareparts data
        ];
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_sparepart');
        $this->db->where('tb_sparepart.id_jenis', $data_kendaraan->id_jenis);
        $query_sparepart = $this->db->get();
        
        foreach ($query_sparepart->result() as $data_sparepart) {
            $spareparts = [
                'id_sparepart' => $data_sparepart->id_sparepart,
                'sparepart' => $data_sparepart->sparepart,
            ];
            array_push($hasil['spareparts'], $spareparts);
        }
    }
    return $hasil;
}
```

Then on the html side, try to modify the codes like this :

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="tambah" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah Pemeliharaan</h3>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Data/Pemeliharaan/Tambah">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Nama Kendaraan</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <select class="form-control"  name="id_kendaraan" id="id_kendaraan" required>
                            <option>Pilih Kendaraan</option>
                            <?php
                            if(!empty($kendaraan_)) {
                            foreach ($kendaraan_ as $isi) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $isi['id_kendaraan']?>"><?php echo $isi['nama']?> - <?php echo $isi['platno']?></option>
                            <?php }} ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $index =0;          
                    foreach ($subkriteria_ as $kr_key => $kriteria) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><?php echo $kriteria['nama_kriteria'] ?></label> 
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input type="hidden" name="status_pemeliharaan" value="1" class="form-control">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_kriteria[]" value="<?php echo $kriteria['id_kriteria'] ?>" class="form-control">  
                            <?php if(!empty($kriteria['sub'])) { ?> 
                            <select class="form-control"  name="isi_kriteria[]" required>
                                <option>Pilih Sub Kriteria</option>
                                <?php $no = 1; foreach ($kriteria['sub'] as $data)     { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['namasubkriteria'] ?> - <?php echo $data['value'] ?></option>
                                <?php  $no++; } ?>
                            </select>
                            <?php } else if($kriteria['link']=='tahun_beli') { ?>
                                <input name="isi_kriteria[]" value="" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Isi Kriteria..." readonly required>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <input name="isi_kriteria[]" value="" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Isi Kriteria..." required>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">tes</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <ul id="sparepartList" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Tutup</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_kendaraan').on('input',function(){
            
            var id_kendaraan=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo base_url('Data/Pemeliharaan/GetKendaraanById')?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {id_kendaraan: id_kendaraan},
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#sparepartList').empty(); // clear all sparepart checkboxes
                    $.each(data, function(id_kendaraan, tahun_beli, jenis){
                        $('[name="isi_kriteria[]"]').val(data.tahun_beli);
                        $('[name="id_jenis"]').val(data.id_jenis);
                    });
                    $.each(data.spareparts, function (key, value) {
                        let li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" name="id_sparepart[]" value="' + value.id_sparepart + '" />' +
                                '<input type="text" name="sparepart" value="' + value.sparepart + '" /></li>');
                        $('#sparepartList').append(li);
                    });
                        
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice that I changed the `sparepart` html inputs to an unordered list element, then loop the `sparepart` data retrieved from the ajax response inside it.

Comment: i try this code in postman the result is {
  "tahun_beli": "2008",
  "id_jenis": "4",
  "spareparts": [
    {
      "id_sparepart": "8",
      "sparepart": "roda gede sekali"
    }
  ]
} ,but in view sparepart is showing looping 3x show the checkbox.. is should be 1 checkbox

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTzUt.png  looping at sparepart

Comment: ah you're correct, the second `sparepart` loop should also be separated from the `kendaraan` loops, I've updated my codes.

Answer (score 1):

in Your model

```
    $hasil=array(
                'tahun_beli' => $data->tahun_beli,
                'id_jenis' => $data->id_jenis,
                'id_sparepart' => $data->id_sparepart,
                'sparepart' => $data->sparepart,
                );
```

U should Store data in   $hasil  by using  []

```
   $hasil[]=array(
                'tahun_beli' => $data->tahun_beli,
                'id_jenis' => $data->id_jenis,
                'id_sparepart' => $data->id_sparepart,
                'sparepart' => $data->sparepart,
                );
```

---

Comment: Not work bro, my data is show if i try to select kendaraan, but sparepart checkbox just show 1 data, sparepart data should be show many more data because in my database sparepart is many more... My problem is looping in ajax and looping at the field checkbox